# Equivalent of curl --data-binary in python?

Tags: python

What is the equivalent of:

curl --data-binary @myjarfile.jar localhost:10000/acceptjar

In python with the requests api?

The .jar file is a binary file that gets "posted" to a server that expects to receive the jar file.

Comment: what does this do in r provide function example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't handle errors, but should post a file to a server as an octet stream:

```
import requests
res = requests.post(url='http://example.com/post',
                    data=open('example.file', 'rb'),
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

Comment: It is also [possible](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads) to pass the file object as `data` without reading from it first.

Comment: I was stuck trying out files option in python. That never worked. This is the right method.